# Find the possible values of $a, b, c$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

How would you approach this problem?

> Let
>
> $$10,\; a,\; b,\; c,\; 90$$
>
> be consecutive terms of a sequence. Find the possible values of
>   $a,\; b,\; c$
>
> a) if the sequence is arithmetic.
>   b) if the sequence is geometric.
>
> [**Hint**: What kind of sequences do the terms $10,\; b,\; 90$ form in each case?]

---

**EDIT:**

Here's my working for part *a* -

Since $u_1=10$,

$u_1+4d=90$

$\therefore\; 10+4d=90$

Hence, $\;d=20$

So,

$a=30$
$b=50$
$c=70$

How should I approach part *b*?

Comment: Do you know that a geometric sequence has constant ratio between terms? So if $a=10k$, then every term is $k$ times the previous term. So what is 90 in terms of $k$?

Comment: Hint : The ratio between two consecutive entries is conatant, let us call it $q$. now solve $q^4=9$

Comment: I would approach it by asking what set $a,b,c$ must lie in.  Positive reals, complex numbers, quaternions, what?

Comment: So $a, b, c$ won't be integers? (except for $b$ which is 30)

Comment: No reason to assume they'd be integers.  No reason to assume they wouldn't be.... well if $\frac {u_k - u_0}k$ is an integer then all the terms of the arithmetic sequence will be but not otherwise.  If $\sqrt[k]{\frac {u_k}{u_0}}$ is then all the terms of the geometric sequence will be integers but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $10,b,90$ form an arithmetic sequence so that $b=\dfrac{10+90}2$. You find $a,c,$ similarly.

b) $10,b,90$ form a geometric sequence so that $b=\sqrt{10\cdot90}$. You find $a,c,$ similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really helped a lot. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should approach it the exact same way.

You figured if the sequence were arithmetic that there is a $d$ so that $u_{k+1} = u_k + d$ so

$90 =u_5 = d + u_4 = 2d + u_3=3d+u_2 = 4d+u_1$

And $u_1 = 10$ so $4d = 90-10$ or $d = 20$.

If the sequence is geometric then there is an $r$ so that $u_{k+1} = r*u_k$.

So $90 = u_5 = r*u_4 = r^2 *u_3=r^3*u_2 = r^4*u_1$

And $u_1 =10$ so $r^4 =\frac {90}{10}$ or $r = \sqrt 3$. (or $-\sqrt 3$)

.....

I guess the hint is that if you had a three terms arithmetic sequence $10, b ,90$ then $b$ is the arithmetic average $\frac {10+90}2= 50$.  And $10, a, 50$ so $a= \frac {10+50}2$ and $50, c, 90$ so $c = \frac {50+90}2$ can be easily solved.

And if you have a geometric sequence $10, b, 90$ then $b$ is the *geometric* average of $\sqrt{10*90} = 30$.  And so $10, a,30$ would have $a = \sqrt{10*30}$ and $30,c, 90$ would have $c =\sqrt{30*90}$.

Great!  I love that hint!

(You can view my edit history to see my inconsistancy....)

Comment: Also, $r$ might be $-\sqrt3$.

Comment: Good point.....